# Stop Tail when a certain string is found in log file

Tags: linux, string, tail

Need to monitor a log file for a particular string "Server running at http". Once that string is found in the log file , I need to stop checking and want to continue to rest of the code.

currently I am currently using "tail -f my-file.log | grep -q "Server running at http" . But this doesn't seem to work.tail command is still running.

```
tail -f my-file.log | grep -q "Server running at http"
```

Comment: Do check out my updated answer it can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
tail -f my-file.log | awk '/Server running at http/ { print | bash file_with_code}'
```

P.S. instead of a different file it can be a function within the same script, needless to say that in such a case you will not need to say bash before function

Another possible solution can be:

```
tail -f my-file.log | egrep -m 1 "Server running at http";echo "found the pattern"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify, how many matches you need. As you need first hit

```
tail -f server.log | grep -m 1 "mystring"
```

once "mystring" found for the first hit, program will exit automatically.

Comment: tail is still running.. It finds the pattern and print it.. but tail doesn't stop..